# How to communicate between two virtual box hosts

Tags: virtualbox

Host : windows 8.1

guest1(server1 running) : ubuntu 14.04

guest2(server2 running):ubuntu 14.04

**What I have Done**

I have forward port 8558 in guest1 for handle request from main host.and its works fine.Now I want request from guest1 to guest2 server which is running  at port 5672.For that i have forward 5672 port in guest2.

**Problem**

When i connect to guest2 it fail.
I m not able get request in guest2.

How to resolve this issues?

Comment: same problem I have .. !! I am sending HttpRequest from my host windows  and  my virtual box two guest OS ! In First Os Webservices run and second guest run another server but port forwarding issue !! My web server is not finding another server which is running in second guest !! Please give some idea !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using two Debian VM's and I can access one VM from the other and vice versa. Using Ubuntu VM's should make no differences. Here is my settings:

**VirtualBox** :  5.0.24 r108355

**Host** : OS X 10.11.5

**VM1**  : Debian Jessie

**VM2**  : Debian Stretch

**On the host** :

1) Create a NatNetwork :

```
VirtualBox -> Preferences -> Network -> NAT Networks -> Add new NAT Network
```

2) Create a Host-only network:

```
VirtualBox -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-only Networks -> Add host-only network
```

3) On each guest, add one Nat network and one Host only adapter attached to the same interface you created on the host. Choose Paravirtualized Network (virtio-net) as Adapter Type.

**In the VM1 (Debian Jessie)**

4) Modify `/etc/network/interfaces`like this

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

**In the VM2 (Debian Stretch)**

5) Modify `/etc/network/interfaces`like this

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

Note that in Debian stretch the network interace naming scheme has changed. Interfaces are named `enp0s*` and no more `eth*`.

**After this point everything should be operational. The rest of the answer is only for information purpose.**

Each guest will have two IP adresses, one for host-only communication and one for internet access.

**In the VM1 (Debian Jessie)**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:09:e8:02  
          inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:e802/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:330 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:168 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:52722 (51.4 KiB)  TX bytes:21827 (21.3 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:8a:dc:96  
          inet addr:10.0.2.4  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe8a:dc96/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:462 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:421 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:61578 (60.1 KiB)  TX bytes:38012 (37.1 KiB)
```

**In the VM2 (Debian Stretch)**

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fedc:d009  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:dc:d0:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 75  bytes 19672 (19.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 81  bytes 10902 (10.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe4b:811e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:4b:81:1e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 329  bytes 39627 (38.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 231  bytes 30290 (29.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**The routing table in VM1**

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.56.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Same principle in VM2.

Comment: If you are behind a corporate proxy, don't forget it. https://superuser.com/questions/78157/configure-virtualbox-to-connect-to-internet-through-proxy